# apex: TypeError: Class advice impossible in Python3

Tags: python, pytorch, apex

i installed apex:

```
pip uninstall apex
```

My configurations are as follows:

- torch version 1.7.1
- python version 3.7
- cuda 11.0

I came across this error after running import pytorch:

```
TypeError: Class advice impossible in Python3. Use the @implementer class decorator instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled the old version of apex and reinstalled a new version. It worked. Thanks.

```
git clone https://www.github.com/nvidia/apex
cd apex
python setup.py install
```